# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title')

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I am trying to add a query param to my link button in pug it should render a pre populated form of the product i want to edit but i keep getting an error in my console which says "*Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title')*" it says this for my imageUrl, price etc, But they have been defined.

admin.js

```
const Product = require('../models/product');

exports.getAddProduct = (req, res, next) => {
    //res.render(path.join(rootDir, 'views', '/add-product.pug'))
      res.render('admin/edit-product', 
      {pageTitle: 'Add Product', 
      path: '/admin/add-product',
      editing: false
     });
   }

exports.postAddProduct=  (req, res, next) => {
    const title = req.body.title;
    const imageUrl = req.body.imageUrl;
    const price = req.body.price;
    const description = req.body.description;
    const product = new Product(title, imageUrl, description, price);
    product.save();
    res.redirect('/');
};

exports.getEditProduct = (req, res, next) => {
      const editMode = req.query.edit;
      if (!editMode) {
          return res.redirect('/');
      }
      const prodId = req.params.productId;
      Product.findById(prodId, product => {
          if (!product) {
              res.redirect('/')
          }
        res.render('admin/edit-product', 
        {pageTitle: 'Edit Product', 
        path: '/admin/edit-product',
        editing: editMode, 
        product: product
       });
      });
   };

exports.getProducts = (req, res, next) => {
    Product.fetchAll((products) => {
        res.render('admin/products', {
        prods: products, 
        pageTitle: 'Admin Products',
        path: '/admin/products'
        });
    });
}
```

edit-product.pug

```
extends ../layouts/main-layout.pug 

block styles    
    link(rel="stylesheet", href="/css/product.css")
    link(rel="stylesheet", href="/css/forms.css")

block content
    main  
        .main-form
            if editing
                form(action="/admin/edit-product", method="POST")
                    .main-input
                        label(for="title") Title  
                        input(type="text", name="title", placeholder="Search Product", value=product.title) 
                    .main-input
                        label(for="imageUrl") Image URL 
                        input(type="url", name="imageUrl", id="imageUrl", value=product.imageUrl)
                    .main-input
                        label(for="price") Price
                        input(type="number", name="price", id="price", step="0.01", value=product.price) 
                    .main-input
                        label(for="description", value=product.description) Description
                        textarea(name="description", id="description", rows="5") 
                    .main-button  
                        if editing  
                            button.btn(type="submit") Update Product 
                        else 
                            button.btn(type="submit") Add Product
            else
                form(action="/admin/add-product", method="POST")
                    .main-input
                        label(for="title") Title  
                        input(type="text", name="title", placeholder="Search Product") 
                    .main-input
                        label(for="imageUrl") Image URL 
                        input(type="url", name="imageUrl", id="imageUrl")
                    .main-input
                        label(for="price") Price
                        input(type="number", name="price", id="price", step="0.01") 
                    .main-input
                        label(for="description") Description
                        textarea(name="description", id="description", rows="5") 
                    .main-button  
                        if editing  
                            button.btn(type="submit") Update Product 
                        else 
                            button.btn(type="submit") Add Product
```

products.pug

```
extends ../layouts/main-layout.pug 

block styles    
    link(rel="stylesheet", href="/css/main.css")
    link(rel="stylesheet", href="/css/card.css")

block content
    main 
        if prods.length > 0
            .grid 
                each product in prods
                    article.product-item 
                        header.card__header 
                            h1.product__title #{product.title}
                        .card__image 
                            img(src=`${product.imageUrl}` 
                            alt="#{product.title}")
                        .card__content 
                            h2.product__price #{product.price}
                            p.product__description #{product.description}
                        .card__actions 
                            a(href="/admin/edit-product/:product.id:?edit=true") Edit 
                            form(action="/admin/delete-product" method="POST")
                                .btn
                                    button(class="btn", type="submit")  Remove
        else 
            h1 No Product
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that response in your console because you are trying to access a property from an object that does not exist in memory.

The problem is on the object. You believe that the object is defined when that is not the case.

To fix an error like this, you look to the particular object from which you are trying to access property(ies)

I do not have an idea of your running environment but I am assuming that you a making a network call to a database to query your Products.

So, I am using native async-await to handle asynchronous calls.

If you are not making a network call, you can remove async and await wherever they occur in the code below.

Make the following modification to your request handlers:

```js
exports.getEditProduct = async (req, res, next) => {
      const editMode = req.query.edit;
      if (!editMode) {
          return res.redirect('/');
      }
      const prodId = req.params.productId;
      const product = await Product.findById(prodId)
      if (!product) {
          res.redirect('/')
      }
      res.render('admin/edit-product', {
           pageTitle: 'Edit Product', 
           path: '/admin/edit-product',
           editing: editMode, 
           product: product
       });
   };

exports.getProducts = async(req, res, next) => {
    const products = await Product.fetchAll({})
    res.render('admin/products', {
        prods: products, 
        pageTitle: 'Admin Products',
        path: '/admin/products'
    });
}
```

Let me know if this helped you resolve the issue.

I will be glad to assist more

Answer (score 0):

now when i do make these changes you have stated, i get an error saying

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length') in my
'products.pug' file
this wasnt happening before until these changes were made.

my 'products.pug' file

```
extends ../layouts/main-layout.pug 

block styles    
    link(rel="stylesheet", href="/css/main.css")
    link(rel="stylesheet", href="/css/card.css")

block content
    main 
        if prods.length > 0
            .grid 
                each product in prods
                    article.product-item 
                        header.card__header 
                            h1.product__title #{product.title}
                        .card__image 
                            img(src=`${product.imageUrl}` 
                            alt="#{product.title}")
                        .card__content 
                            h2.product__price #{product.price}
                            p.product__description #{product.description}
                        .card__actions 
                            a(href="/admin/edit-product/:product.id:?edit=true") Edit 
                            form(action="/admin/delete-product" method="POST")
                                .btn
                                    button(class="btn", type="submit")  Remove
        else 
            h1 No Product
```